# Query an image using Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using parse with Swift and I am trying to bring up and post an image from Parse on to my tableView but I keep receiving in the log

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value

here's my code for querying the image:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class HomePage: UITableViewController {

var images = [UIImage]()
var titles = [String]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    println(PFUser.currentUser())

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
    //query.whereKey("username", equalTo:followedUser)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            for object in objects! {

                // Update - replaced as with as!

                self.titles.append(object["Title"] as! String)


                // Update - replaced as with as!

                self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println(error)
        }
    }




    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return titles.count


}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 500

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell



    myCell.rank.text = "21"
    myCell.votes.text = "4012"
    myCell.postDescription.text = titles[indexPath.row]

    return myCell

    }

}
```

Also I get the one line of code highlighted in green which is this :

```
self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to make the the code pull up the image from Parse?

now its no longer giving me the error unwrapped nil but it still shows

```
self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
```

in green highlighting and the app keeps crashing when i open it.

[image: the error i keep getting when i run the app]

this is my parse backend in case that might be an issue:

[image: parse]

Comment: does your scores println return a value? is the json key for images really named "imageFile"? it seems that your cast might go wrong - can you log out the whole json response from parse?

Comment: I think the problem is inserting nil into the array.  Either insure that the "imageFile" column is always populated, or wrap the append in some defensive code that appends conditionally if the column is non-nil.

Comment: @longbow yes it returns 4 just like it should and yes the file name is imageFile from what i can tell. I am not sure how to logout the json response?

Comment: what do you see in the console if you log out println(objects) does it already enumerate the parse response (which is highly likely json) into objects? €dit: furthermore i wouldnt make just an array of images, i would do a dictionary of [id:image], as all your images are named the same

Comment: @longbow im fairly new to xcode sorry i dont think i completely understand your question regarding the log out println(objects)? thank you i will work on turning it into a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the issue by adding in the ovveride func UITableviewCell

```
imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

            }

        }
```

i think this worked because i got rid of the if error == nil and now its working great for me.